# hippocrates moons for any shape

Tags: geometry

Can someone help me create code for a [hippocrates moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_of_Hippocrates) on random shape with given amount of edges? I want to make something like this:

when you press button, it asks you for the amount of edges/points you want, then it adds given amount of point in random spots on a circle (R=constant) and draws shape from it. Each side of the shape has small circle on the middle with diameter of the same lenght as that side.

Heres what I managed to do so far:
Triangle with adjustable sides lenght:

```
Button["show", 
 Print[Animate[
   Show[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, b/2`}, b/2`], Blue, 
      Disk[{a/2, 0}, a/2], RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
      Disk[{a/2, b/2`}, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]/2], RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
      Circle[{a/2, b/2`}, Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]/2], Red, 
      Polygon[{{0, 0}, {a, 0}, {0, b}}], RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
      Line[{{-b/2, b/2}, {0, b/2}}], Line[{{a/2, 0}, {a/2, -a/2}}], 
      Line[{{0, 0}, {a, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, b}}], 
      Line[{{0, b}, {a, 0}}], Thick, Line[{{a/2, b/2}, {a, 0}}], 
      Line[{{a/2, b/2}, {a/2 + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]/2, b/2}}]}, {Axes -> 
       True, AxesStyle -> Black}], 
    AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}, 
    PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Triangle], LabelStyle -> {Black},
     Frame -> Automatic], {a, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {b, 1, 
    5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, AnimationRate -> 0.5, 
   AnimationRunning -> False]], Method -> "Queued"]
```

I want to do something like this but for random point placement and for given amount of points (program ask u how many points you want). Animate is not required here, just the image.

I only managed to put random points on circle and I am stuck. This is the code:

```
f[] := Block[{u, t, r}, u = Random[] + Random[];
  t = Random[] 2 Pi;
  r = 1;
  {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}]
a = Sort[Table[f[], {4}]]
ListPlot[a, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Help please

Answer (score 2):

Your request is unclear.  Nevertheless, this code generates Hippocrates moons, which should serve as a start.

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 > 1 && (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 < c^2,
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  PlotPoints -> 50],
 {{a, 1}, -2, 2},
 {{b, 1}, -2, 2},
 {{c, 1}, .1, 3}]
```

If you sketch by hand a figure you desire, that would help us greatly.

Comment: Just use the code I posted for triangle - I want figure like this but with randomly generated edges and for set amount of edges.